# Home Page Slider is hiding mega menu

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, css, menu

The site i'm working on:  http://www.acuity-sports.com/

I've been tinkering around with the theme.css file and with the relative positions & the z-index as well.

I've been reading this page for advise 
coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

However i'm trying to figure out what needs to be adjusted to fix the hidden mega menu on the site.   I swapped the top and bottom around here is the original theme

http://demo.magentech.com/#sm-sport

Any advice would rock :)

Comment: Hi runde and welcome to magento.stackexchange.com. I'm sorry but this question is not magento related, therefore it will be closed. Better try it on stackoverflow.com! (if I were a frontend guy I would help you :-))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a css problem.

Comment: thanks!  I will try that!  I did however fix it  :)  my .header-bottom .header-nav {  /* position:relative; */ margin-left: 10px;  } had a Z-index of 2 and I just had to remove that to get it to display properly

Comment: Great! Hope you will come back and ask new questions or answer a few :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit off-topic,
but if you just change line 145 in your megamenu.css like so:

```
.sm_megamenu_wrapper_horizontal_menu .sm_megamenu_menu li.sm_megamenu_lv1.sm_megamenu_drop > div {
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1000
}
```

(Or whatever z-index you would like to be above the slideshow) it will work.

Comment: Thanks mate!  Sorry it was in the wrong forum but appreciate your help